# Highlight matched text when data is returned through backbone filters

Tags: backbone.js

I am using backbone filters for search.
Below is my code in collection.

```
search : function(data){

    var pattern = new RegExp(data,"gi");
    return (this.filter(function(model) {
        console.log("found match in "+ (model.get("name")).match(pattern));
        return pattern.test(model.get("name"));
    }));
}
```

Below is my code in view:

```
render: function () {
    var data = new GroupCollection(this.collection.search(searchData)).toJSON();
    var html = this.template(data);
    this.$el.html(html);
    return this;
},
```

Above search code is working fine.

I want to hightlight the search data in results but can't find a way to do this.

I am getting the search data. But I am not able to highlight the matched text as in below image.

[image]

using match in regular expression able to get the matched text but how that can be showed in my template.

Comment: can you add jsfiddle with a simple example on your problem?

Comment: yes. fiddle your code. i also can give a try.

Comment: @user10 : Here is the fiddle.. I am using hadlebar template. Didn't find the url of handlebar to attach in external source so didn't do that. Its my first time making backbone fiddle so not able to work. Just put my code in it. http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/86/

Comment: @ekeren : Here is the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/86/ .I am using hadlebar template. Didn't find the url of handlebar to attach in external source so didn't do that. Its my first time making backbone fiddle so not able to work. Just put my code in it. sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: @Cindrella handlebar - http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js. Ok let me add and look at it.

Comment: @Cindrella posted an answer. is that helpful?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34155/discussion-between-user10-and-cindrella)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/106/)

use **Handlebars.registerHelper**

**sample code:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(name) {
    var searchString = 'com'; //$("#txtSearch").val();

    var dom = name.replace(searchString, '<span style="color: red">' 
                                         + searchString + '</span>');
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(dom);
});
```

Comment: sorry didn't check that.. my net disconnected. trying now.

Comment: Yeah I know about registerHelper but when the filter is returning data how can we apply the registerHelper to that matched text in collection. since I have written my search functionality in collection.